# How to get the partition data without using PARTITION function

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a older mysql version and it do not support PARTITION keyword. But I could see my table have partitions and it is updating fine.

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";
+-------------------------+----------------------+
| Variable_name           | Value                |
+-------------------------+----------------------+
| innodb_version          | 5.5.59-MariaDB-38.11 |
| protocol_version        | 10                   |
| slave_type_conversions  |                      |
| version                 | 5.5.60-MariaDB       |
| version_comment         | MariaDB Server       |
| version_compile_machine | x86_64               |
| version_compile_os      | Linux                |
+-------------------------+----------------------+
7 rows in set (0.01 sec)

******
 ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
/*!50100 PARTITION BY RANGE (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(start_time))
(PARTITION p20220802 VALUES LESS THAN (1659465000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20220803 VALUES LESS THAN (1659551400) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20220804 VALUES LESS THAN (1659637800) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20220805 VALUES LESS THAN (1659724200) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20220806 VALUES LESS THAN (1659810600) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20220807 VALUES LESS THAN (1659897000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20220808 VALUES LESS THAN (1659983400) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20220809 VALUES LESS THAN (1660069800) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p20220810 VALUES LESS THAN (1660156200) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p_max_future_dates VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE ENGINE = InnoDB) */ |
****
```

But when I use following queries I am getting syntax errors..

```
MariaDB [(none)]> select count(*) from db.table1 partition(p20220810) ;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(p20220810)' at line 1
MariaDB [(none)]>
```

Are there any method to without using PARTITION?

Update:

```
MariaDB [rsmcdr]> SELECT PLUGIN_NAME as Name, PLUGIN_VERSION as Version, PLUGIN_STATUS as Status FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PLUGINS WHERE PLUGIN_TYPE='STORAGE ENGINE'; 
+--------------------+---------+--------+
| Name               | Version | Status |
+--------------------+---------+--------+
| binlog             | 1.0     | ACTIVE |
| MEMORY             | 1.0     | ACTIVE |
| CSV                | 1.0     | ACTIVE |
| MyISAM             | 1.0     | ACTIVE |
| MRG_MYISAM         | 1.0     | ACTIVE |
| Aria               | 1.5     | ACTIVE |
| BLACKHOLE          | 1.0     | ACTIVE |
| FEDERATED          | 2.0     | ACTIVE |
| ARCHIVE            | 3.0     | ACTIVE |
| InnoDB             | 5.5     | ACTIVE |
| PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA | 0.1     | ACTIVE |
| partition          | 1.0     | ACTIVE |
+--------------------+---------+--------+
12 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

Comment: Please add output from SELECT
         PLUGIN_NAME as Name,
         PLUGIN_VERSION as Version,
         PLUGIN_STATUS as Status
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PLUGINS
        WHERE PLUGIN_TYPE='STORAGE ENGINE';

Comment: Added as required

Comment: Select ...Where...